# How to extract 'for'/'to' address from header in outlook 2007+ using VBA Script

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I am using the BlueDevilFan VBA script to show me internet headers from an email within Outlook 2013. I have been trying to modify the VBA so that it only outputs the 'to' or 'for' address and discards all other text,

Below is the VBA script:

```
 Sub ViewInternetHeader()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem, olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strheader As String

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        strheader = GetInetHeaders(olItem)

        Set olMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With olMsg
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            .Body = strheader
            .Display
        End With
    Next
    Set olMsg = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetInetHeaders(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    ' Purpose: Returns the internet headers of a message.'
    ' Written: 4/28/2009'
    ' Author:  BlueDevilFan'
    ' http://techniclee.wordpress.com/
    ' Outlook: 2007'
    Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
    GetInetHeaders = olkPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS)
    Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

I have tried something like i would use in word to find and delete certain content, but cannot get it working in outlook!

```
Sub CleanUp()
With Selection
.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
With .Find
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Text = "(\To: """)"
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchWildcards = True
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
.Text = "(\To: """)"
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just clear out the text of the body and then add the to and from ie sender

```
Sub ViewInternetHeader()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem, olMsg As Outlook.MailItem


    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection


        Set olMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        olMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        olMsg.Body = ""
        olMsg.Body = olItem.To & Chr(13) & olItem.Sender
        olMsg.Display
    Next
    Set olMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, throws error on "Block variable not set" on line: olMsg.Body = olMsg.To & Chr(13) & olMsg.Sender

Comment: @nickrenwick   Fixed, the sender and to have to come from olItem

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to extract the addresses from the headers? Just loop through all recipients in the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and if `Recipient.Type = olTo`, read the `Recipient.Address` property/

Comment: The emails in question are all alias' filtering into one mailbox, because they are alias' the main recipient will always show the mailbox name and not necessarily what the email was sent to.

Comment: Ok. So what is the problem parsing the value of the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_HEADERS property?